# Taxonomy - populate child dropdown based on parent dropdown?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am wondering if there is a way to populate a taxonomy dropdown menu with the child terms of a selection made in another taxonomy dropdown menu. I would like to have two taxonomy dropdown menus, one for genre (parent) and one for sub-genre (child). When the a selection is made in the genre menu, I'd like the child sub-genre terms for that genre appear in the menu. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 6, a good way to do this is to use a single taxonomy vocabulary and make the children terms selectable via [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).  This will give you a single menu of the parents and then when users select one of the parent terms the menu of related children will automatically appear.

However, Hierarchical Select hasn't yet been fully ported to Drupal 7 (most notably, Views support does not work at all) and the timetable to do so is unknown.

For Drupal 7, you could try using the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module (or just use the [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) directly if you're a developer) to set up logic to show/hide child menus based on the value of the parent menu.  However, doing so has two big drawbacks:

1. Users will see all fields if they have Javascript disabled.
2. Depending on the number of items you have, this can get very complicated.

Comment: I'm on D7, so those are two large drawbacks indeed. That's unfortunate. Thanks for the thorough answer though, as always.